# Can I safely remove Upstart?

Tags: 17.04, upstart, software-uninstall

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. AFAIK, Upstart functionality was replaced by Systemd long time ago.

I've always been upgrading releases via `do-release-upgrade` (not clean installs) and I noticed that package `upstart` is still installed on my system, although it does not seem to be running (`pgrep -f upstart` shows no results), and `apt purge upstart --dry-run` shows no dependencies on this package.

I wonder if package `upstart` can be safely removed.

Comment: The package is there for compatibility. Don't remove it.